# I want to get the encoded string as output . But not able to

Tags: c++, string, binary, crc

Input:

```
101101110
1101
```

Expected Ouput:

```
000000000011
```

My output:

It just keeps on taking the input.and not showing any output.

Please help me . what is wrong with my code. Any help would be aprreciated.I have given the names of the variables such that its easy to understand.This code is only for the senders side.

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        string input;
        string polynomial;
        string encoded="";
        cin>>input;
        cin>>polynomial;
        int input_len=input.length();
        int poly_len=polynomial.length();
        encoded=encoded+input;
        for(int i=1;i<=poly_len-1;i++){
            encoded=encoded+'0';
        }
        for(int i=0;i<=encoded.length()-poly_len;){
            for(int j=0;j<poly_len;j++){
                if(encoded[i+j]==polynomial[j]){
                    encoded[i+j]=='0';
                }
                else{
                    encoded[i+j]=='1';
                }
            }
            while(i<encoded.length() && encoded[i]!='1'){
                i++;
            }
        }
        cout<<encoded;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: turn on your compiler warnings: https://godbolt.org/z/Kna3o8z8W. Most of them point to serious bugs in the code. After you fixed them you should use a debugger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at these lines properly:

```
if (encoded[i + j] == polynomial[j]) {
    encoded[i + j] == '0'; // Line 1
}
else {
    encoded[i + j] == '1'; // Line 2
}
```

See? You are using `==` while you should be using `=`. `==` is a comparison operator which returns a `boolean` (true/false). It does not assign values. So to fix your problem, replace the above lines with:

```
if (encoded[i + j] == polynomial[j]) {
    encoded[i + j] = '0'; // Replaced == with =
}
else {
    encoded[i + j] = '1'; // Replaced == with =
}
```

This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

My tip for you is to get familiar with debugging. Try adding some breakpoints in your code so you can actually see what is  happening behind. After checking your code it seems that this line is giving an infinite loop `for(int i=0;i<=encoded.length()-poly_len;)`. The condition won't be true at any point after entering the input you gave us.

Comment: The reason of not getting any output is the infinite loop, but it's not the main issue. The problem is using the `comparison operator` (`==`) instead of the `assignment operator` (`=`).

Comment: Haven't seen it at first, but you are of course right.